# importing multiple project(maven2) into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a giant project that consists of multiple projects (>100).
They are all configured to be compiled using maven2.

Using maven 2 on the commandline works well but I want to import these projects into eclipse.

I have installed the following plug-ins:

- JRebel m2eclipse integration(experimental)
- m2e connector for mavenarchiver pom properties
- m2e connector for modello
- M2E lifecycle  configuration for the Axistools Maven Plugin
- Maven Integration for WTP
- Multi Project Import/Export

As I'm totally green working with eclipse and Maven. I have just worked blindly (trial and error) and feel like lightyears from success.

The main problem is all unresolvable imports I get and I'm sure that it must be a way to solve it without to much effort as it works if you run it from the commandline using maven directly.

Using eclipse 3.7.

Would be happy if someone could help me by giving some clues how to import maven projects into eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Before importing your projects? This creates .project and .classpath files needed by Eclipse to import projects into workspace.

Comment: No, I have not.  Do I need to be on any specific library/catalog when I type it?

Comment: You have to be in the root folder of the project to import in eclipse (where you have the pom.xml). Maven will download the plugin to create Eclipse project specific files. I think you hav to do it for all maven modules, to import them, but not sure.

Comment: Ok, this made a difference, but I also found another menuitem at Import - Import Existing Maven Projects.

Comment: You should not use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` if you're using m2eclipse. With m2e you use the import tool as you just said.

Comment: I used - Import Existing Projects Into Workspace -  instead. I also think by using this menu entry I don't need to do "mvn eclipse:eclipse" or ?  Now I just get around 1000 errors instead of 100000 errors. An improvement but now I got some strange JAVA-errors like "The method m1 of type t1 must override a superclass method" Of course it does, it works when compiling from the command line. Another problem is that the POM-files are in error now. It's the first line that looks like this: <? xml-version=1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  What's wrong with that? It doesn't tell.

Comment: hleinone, thank's. What happends if if I did just that - running "mvn eclipse:eclipse" when using m2eclipse? Could that be the problem with my POM-files?

Comment: mvn eclipse:eclipse just creates the two files I mentioned in the answer to let you import the project as an "Existing Project". No changes to the pom. The "Import Existing Maven Project" let the m2eclipse do an "mvn eclipse:eclipse"'s like work for you.